# Pass date range in rdlc report vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rdlc

Need help
I am using sql server 2016, visual studio 2017
In my report i am unable to pass date range, when report is loading its showing all records from beginning to till date, where am mistake pls help!!
Below code is am made in 1 function and calling on button click

````vb
Dim strSQL As String = "", strSQLID As String = "", strSQLOrderBy As String = ""
            Dim query As String = " select o.InvoiceDate,o.RegistrationNo,o.PatientName,o.TransactionStatus,o.gender,o.company,o.Visittype,o.Doctor,o.Specialisation,"
            query &= " o.departmentName,o.Address,o.CityName,o.StateName,o.MobileNo,o.ServiceName"
            query &= " from DRT_VW_OPVISIT o "
            query &= " inner join employee e on o.DoctorId=e.ID "
            'query &= " where e.ID in ('') "
            query &= " where convert(varchar,o.InvoiceDate,111) between '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + " ' and '" + DateTimePicker2.Text + "' "
            query &= " and  o.TransactionStatus='Active' "
            'query &= " order by InvoiceDate desc "

            If Trim(strID) <> "" Then strSQLID = strSQLID & " And e.ID In (" + strID + ")"
            strSQLOrderBy = " order by o.InvoiceDate desc "

            conn = GetConnect()
            conn.Open()

            query = query & strSQLID & strSQLOrderBy
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            MsgBox(query)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTimePicker1", Me.DateTimePicker1.Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTimePicker2", Me.DateTimePicker2.Value)

            Dim sda1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds1 As New DataSet1
            Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable()
            sda1.Fill(dt2)


            With RepDoctorWiseVisit.ReportViewer1.LocalReport

                .ReportPath = "D:\VB Project 2021\RepDepartmentWisePrice\RepDepartmentWisePrice\Report3.rdlc"
                .DataSources.Clear()
                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt2))
            End With
            RepDoctorWiseVisit.Show()
            RepDoctorWiseVisit.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

            Return dt2

```
````

Comment: Careful, the above is *wide* open to injection attacks. You **need** to fix that huge security hole; it's a vulnerability just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: You are also using .AddWithValue - which will add the parameters with unicode data types that can cause problems with how the query executes.  You should use add and define the data type to match the SQL data type.

Comment: And - you should not convert a date column to a varchar and then try to compare that value using between for dates.  Use an open-interval range such as: o.InvoiceDate >= @startDate And o.InvoiceDate < dateadd(day, 1, @endDate) - and define start/end dates with 00:00:00.000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of different things in your sample code that will cause you some issue.  You need to do some reading on using Sql Parameters in your TSQL commands.  As pointed out by Larnu, security is an issue but the real benefit to you as a developer is it is a million times easier to debug.
I've also made an assumption here DRT_VW_OPVISIT.InvoiceDate is a DateTime column in your DB.
Anyway, try this for a start

Also, just a note.  If it is a Date Time, you will in all likelihood need to adjust for the time component

```
        Dim strSQL As String = "", strSQLID As String = "", strSQLOrderBy As String = ""

        Dim query As String = " select o.InvoiceDate,o.RegistrationNo,o.PatientName,o.TransactionStatus,o.gender,o.company,o.Visittype,o.Doctor,o.Specialisation,"
        query &= " o.departmentName,o.Address,o.CityName,o.StateName,o.MobileNo,o.ServiceName"
        query &= " from DRT_VW_OPVISIT o "
        query &= " inner join employee e on o.DoctorId=e.ID "
        query &= " where o.InvoiceDate between @DateTimePicker1 and @DateTimePicker2 "
        query &= " and  o.TransactionStatus='Active' "

        If Trim(strID) <> "" Then strSQLID = strSQLID & " And e.ID In (" + strID + ")"
        strSQLOrderBy = " order by o.InvoiceDate desc "

        conn = GetConnect()
        conn.Open()

        query = query & strSQLID & strSQLOrderBy
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        MsgBox(query)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTimePicker1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTimePicker2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.DateTimePicker2.Value

        Dim sda1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet1
        Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable()
        sda1.Fill(dt2)


        With RepDoctorWiseVisit.ReportViewer1.LocalReport

            .ReportPath = "D:\VB Project 2021\RepDepartmentWisePrice\RepDepartmentWisePrice\Report3.rdlc"
            .DataSources.Clear()
            .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt2))
        End With
        RepDoctorWiseVisit.Show()
        RepDoctorWiseVisit.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

        Return dt2
```

I Will also warn you, there are a number of other improvements you can make, things like wrapping your connection in a "Using" block will keep that clean.  And don't get me started on the hard coded report path.
I'm not saying this is a complete answer, but hopefuly I've given you the info to go get what you need yourself